# what's the difference between point-to-point links and unicasting?

Tags: networking

I read them from the COMPUTER NETWORKs. but i cannot tell from them.

Do they refer the same thing?

point-to-point links means source and destination module (may be through some intermediate machine)

see from the words, it means one point and another.(Just two point)

So, it seems the same meaning with Unicasting.

What's the difference?

Comment: What is a link? Answer that question and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicasting is a transport-layer action that happens *over* a link.

Comment: is point to point link unicasting? i just want to know the difference

Comment: @luthur I've just answered that. They happen at different layers. They aren't the same thing.